# Odata query on specific table columns

Tags: select, filter, odata

I'm trying to getting column-specific results while querying an odata service like shown below:

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers?$filter=ID%20eq%201
```

The result contains values for the columns ID, Name, Adress, Location and Concurrency. How can I adjust the url-filter so the response contains only values for the columns ID and name, while the ID must be '1'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

Already found the answer, I should be using a $select parameter in the url like this:

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers?$select=Name, ID, &$filter=ID eq 1
```